# Match Twitter @username, but not emails

Tags: php, regex, twitter

Okay so I am horrible with regular expressions and need some help here. I've found this code to match a twitter username:

```
'/(?<=^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i
```

This works in most cases, except when a HTML tag is placed before the @username, example:

```
<p>@username</p>
```

That's a problem for me since it will happen with what I'm doing.

Then there is this, which works, but also detects email addresses, which isn't what I want:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just run the string through [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) before your `preg_match()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the html tag ending `>` is the problem, add it to your lookbehind group:

```
'/(?<=^|\s|>)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i
```

Comment: That easy eh? Time for me to learn more about regex. Thanks, that worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 1):

As Clive says, first `strip_tags()`. Then you can (untested) match on the username directly.

```
$subject = strip_tags( '<p>@taylorbuley</p>' );
$matches = array();
preg_match( '/$@[A-Za-z0-9_]+^/', $subject, $matches );
var_dump( $matches );
```

The `$` matches the beginning of the line and `^` matches the end of the line so the example above is perhaps overfit to your example. If so, they can be omitted.

For a more holistic view, take a look at [how Twitter does it in JavaScript](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js/blob/master/twitter-text.js#L97).